# "#+STARTUP: hideblocks" won't work. Can't find offending package/setting

Tags: org-mode, debugging

After I upgraded to Org Mode 9.4.5, I learned about the startup option `hideblocks`, but it won't work as advertised for me.

OK, when I start emacs with the flag `-Q`, it did, so I went hunting for culprits in my `.emacs`. All suspicious-looking settings and packages have been removed, but `hideblocks` still doesn't work.

Oddly enough, when I visit a test file  with `#+STARTUP: hideblocks`, the variable `org-hide-block-startup` do indeed change from `nil`, which is default, to `t`. Despite this, the block remains unfolded!

I can make all blocks fold on start-up, if I set `org-hide-block-startup` with a local variables section at the end of the file, but I consider that to be an ugly, last resort solution.

Is there a smart way of tracking down when and where the hideblock setting is reversed, intercepted, toggled, or whatever happens?

---

*Addendum April 4:*

Since writing the above, I stumbled upon one additional interesting symptom. When I was led astray with the theory that my Org Mode installation was somehow faulty, I took a look at the installation instructions in the info documentation. Among other things, it says the following about an org mode installation with elpa:

> Important: You need to do this in a session where no ‘.org’ file
> has been visited, i.e., where no Org built-in function have been
> loaded.  Otherwise autoload Org functions will mess up the
> installation.

So I did `M-x list-packages`, threw out org mode, restarted Emacs, installed org mode anew, and visited my test file.

Lo and behold, my block was folded at start-up.

However, the effect was short-lasting, and trying to open the same file later did not work as expected.

Comment: *"All suspicious-looking settings and packages have been removed"*. Clearly "suspicious-looking" isn't enough. If you see no problem with `emacs -Q` the *bisect* your init file till you've narrowed it down to just what's causing the problem. You can use `comment-region` to bisect it.

Comment: How do you set `org-hide-block-startup` in the first place? Did you `customize` the variable?

Comment: @Drew: I suppose there is no way around that kind of elbow grease in the end.
@NickD: Before I upgraded Org Mode I did nothing. I didn't even know I could control this behaviour at all. This time, I have tried to obtain per file control, with the help of ```#+STARTUP hideblocks```. (As I wrote above, setting ```org-hide-block-startup``` in a local variables section at the end of the file, the blocks start folded. I do not like this workaround, however.)

Comment: Elbow grease? Bisecting is a binary search - very quick. Use `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, 31/32,... till you find exactly what, in your init file, is the culprit. Plain `C-u` with `comment-region` uncomments.

Comment: Right now, I have started wondering if the fact that my Org Mode is "shadowing a built-in package" could have something to do with my problems. I am the kind of lazy guy who has installed Emacs with a Debian package, including an older version of Org Mode. On top of (?) this, I have slapped a newer version of Org Mode with the help of elpa.
Before I write another word on this, I will do my bisection homework...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is much simpler than suggested by my own theories (see above).
It turns out that the intended effect of `#+STARTUP: hideblocks` is overruled by the initial visibility setting `#+STARTUP: showeverything`, which is now default.

So, by combining `#+STARTUP: hideblocks` with `#+STARTUP: showall` or (equivalently) `#+STARTUP: nohide`, the desired effect can be obtained.

N.B. "nohide" is hiding pretty well in the info documentation, but can be found if one looks at the documentation for the variable `org-startup-folded`.

Comment: Here's a [recent discussion](https://orgmode.org/list/ROHUeM54ZefdkWDdlKutztK14Bs29jY2OePKuMLq5xs8I4UFFQpL8Gsdo8ejciIStc24hcPWEElH1izFsDHx8LGThzBDcr0oVjdrDqb5KA0=@protonmail.ch/) of exactly this question on the Org mode ML.

Comment: Should I have `#+STARTUP: folded showall` then?